# How to set value to input type file using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have button where i will browse images and in jquery i am trying to set that browsed images value to hidden input type file .I have tried so many example but i could not able to fix it.In php side i am getting null values.

HTML

```
    <button type="button" value="" id="activityAddOrEditfakeBrowse" onclick="invokeBrowseButtonClick('activityAddOrEditFile');" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i>Upload Documents</button>

 <div id="section2"><!-- for dynamic controls-->
                              </div>
```

JQUERY

```
  var fileCnt = 0;

$('#activityAddOrEditFile').on('change', function(){ 

 var $input = $("<input name='croppedDocumentActivity[]' type='file' id='croppedDocumentActivity"+ (fileCnt + 1) +"' value="+file.name+" class='croppedDocumentActivity'>");
                        fileCnt++;
$('#section2').append($input);
```

Comment: You need to create one more hidden input, then you can set value into that input and can use.

Comment: @RaghbendraNayak.can you provide code so i can try

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="filename.ext" />;
<script>;
  $(function () {
    $("button").on("click", function (event) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".hidden-control").attr("type", "text");
      $("form").submit();
    });
  });
</script>;
```